# django rest framework translation does not work for me

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, internationalization

I tried django rest framework internationalization.

[doc drf internationalization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/internationalization/#internationalization)

From official drf documentation a set this code in settings.py

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = "it"

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('it', _('Italian')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True
```

but when I try out POST api rest

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://172.18.0.1:7000/appjud/api/v1/reset-password/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Token 014cb7982f31767a8ce07c9f216653d4674baeaf' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "new_password": "",
  "confirm_password": ""
}'

Response body
[
  {
    "newpassword": [
      "This field is required."
    ],
    "confirmpassword": [
      "This field is required."
    ]
  }
]

Response headers
allow: POST,OPTIONS  
content-language: en  
content-length: 91  
content-type: application/json  
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin  
date: Sat,03 Dec 2022 16:14:16 GMT  
referrer-policy: same-origin  
server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.9.15  
vary: Accept,Accept-Language,Origin  
x-content-type-options: nosniff  
x-frame-options: DENY
```

**UPDATE**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     ...
]
```

As we can see it print "This field is required." but I would like "Questo campo è obbligatorio."
What Does I miss in config settings.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you added `LocaleMiddleware` to the end of middlewares list. But order is matter here. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference):

> Because middleware order matters, follow these guidelines:
>
> Make sure it’s one of the first middleware installed.
> It should come after SessionMiddleware, because LocaleMiddleware makes use of session data. And it should come before CommonMiddleware
> because CommonMiddleware needs an activated language in order to
> resolve the requested URL.
> If you use CacheMiddleware, put LocaleMiddleware after it.

Try to change order according to this note.

Comment: I have updated MIDDLEWARE settings.